# Rewrtiting the $L^p$-norm with $\mu(\{|f|>t\})$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am looking at an exercise (6.2) in Kesavan's book on Functional Analysis. It says:
Let $(X, S, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $1 \leq p < \infty$. Define, for $t>0$,
$$
h_f(t) = \mu(\{|f| > t\}.
$$
Show that
$$
||f||_p^p = p \int_0^\infty t^{p-1} h_f(t) dt.
$$
The book recommends using Fubini's Theorem.

I have been stuck for quite a while. I thought I would simply start with the $L^1$-case which would imply we need to show that
$$
||f||_1 = \int_0^\infty \int_X \chi_{\{|f|>t\}}(t) d\mu \; dt \\
=  \int_X \int_0^\infty \chi_{\{|f|>t\}}(t) dt \; d\mu.
$$
So there would be the use case for Fubini. I have no clue how to show it. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$L^p$-norm of a non-negative measurable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182019/lp-norm-of-a-non-negative-measurable-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\int_0^\infty \chi_{\{| f(x) | > t\}} dt = \int_0^{| f(x)|} dt = |f(x)|.$$